# Update value based on other input fields

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have created a component for creating dynamic rows with input fields for invoice items.

```
<template>
    <tr>
        <td class="p-0" align="center"><label class="m-0">{{ row.id + 1 }}</label></td>
        <td class="p-0" align="center">
            <input type="text" v-model="row.name" name="product_name[]" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="Product Name ...">
        </td>
        <td class="p-0" align="center">
            <input type="text" v-model="row.hsn" name="product_hsn[]" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="900574">
        </td>
        <td class="p-0" align="center">
            <input type="number" v-model="row.qty" name="product_qty[]" value="1" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="0">
        </td>
        <td class="p-0">
            <input type="number" v-model="row.rate" name="product_rate[]" value="" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="0.00">
        </td>
        <td class="p-0">
            <input type="number" v-model="row.amount" name="product_amount[]" readonly="readonly" v-bind:value="row.qty * row.rate" class="form-control form-control-sm border-0" placeholder="0.00">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: ['row'],
    data() {
        return {
            slabs: [0, 0.25, 3, 5, 12, 18, 28],
        }
    },

    mounted() {}
}
</script>
```

But the value of `v-bind:value="row.qty * row.rate"` is **not getting update**.

This is how i am using this component:

```
<tbody>
       <tr v-for="(row, index) in invoiceRows" v-bind:row="row" v-bind:key="+row" is="invoice-product" v-on:remove="invoiceRows.splice(index, 1)"></tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot class="hidden-print">
       <tr>
              <td class="p-0" colspan="18">
                   <a href="javascript:;" @click="_addRow()" class="p-2 mt-3" style="text-decoration:none;font-size:14px;"><i class="ion-ios-plus" style="font-size:18px;"></i> Add Line</a>
               </td>
         </tr>
 </tfoot>
```

**App.js**

```
....
computed: {
    invoiceRows() {
        return this.$store.state.items
    }
},
```

And this is my vuex that manages all the shared states:

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        activeType: null,
        stateList: [],
        companyState: [],
        items: [{
            id: 0, name: null, hsn: null, qty: 1, rate: null, discount: 0,
            taxSlab: 0, cessRate: null, cessAmount: null
        }],
        billToSupplyState: [],
        shipToSupplyState: []
    },
    actions,
    mutations
})
```

But if i remove `v-model="row.amount"` from my component then it will work. Can anyone please help and let me know what i have missed?

Comment: Maybe it's because your `items: [{... rate: null}]` therefore your `row.amount` cannot be calculated.  

One more thing. You generally shouldn't use value passed by props as your v-model.

Comment: @MatWaligora, with ```items: [{... rate: null}]``` is ok, because if i remove the ```v-model="row.amount"``` then everything works fine. And i need this ```row.amount``` for other calculations

Comment: Ok I know what's wrong,
`v-model="row.amount"` takes over `v-bind:value="row.qty * row.rate"` that's why it only displays your `row.amount` and doesn't calculate your `:value`.
Try working with watchers or computed properties for updating your `row.amount` on `row.rate` / `row.qty` changes. Good luck :)